# recenter-top-bottom failing to observe bottom target in comint

Tags: comint

In emacs-version 28.2, I'm observing my comint managed processes getting into a state when `C-l` is just doing nothing when it would have previously moved the cursor to the bottom of the window and showed me the maximal amount.  Normally `C-l` cycles through three positions, but when my process gets into this state, it goes through `top`, `middle`, "do nothing (stay in middle)", and then back to `top` to repeat the cycle.

I'm trying to reproduce the problem with a minimal example, but am keen to hear if there's anything obvious I should look into.  I did not see this behaviour with emacs 27 (and earlier).

Comment: Consider filing a bug report: `M-x report-emacs-bug`.

Comment: Yeah, I will when I get that nice minimal example.